# Загрузка изображений в OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, изображения, opengl

— Как загружать изображения в программу с использованиям OpenGL и конвертировать в текстуру. Нужна готовая библиотека.

— Какие библиотеки самые распространенные в С++ для работы с изображениями? Конвертация изображений из одного формата в другой, перевод массива пикселей в изображение и тому подобное.

— Вопрос из интереса. Как делают в общем компании и опытные программисты, которым нужно работать с изображениями? Вот они берут готовые библиотеки или пишут свои? Разработчики тех же движков, допустим.

Comment: разделите, пожалуйста, этот текст на вопросы и задайте их по отдельности. в текущем виде текст не укладыватеся в принятый на этом сайте формат: «вопрос-ответ».

Answer (score 3):

> Какой формат изображений лучше использовать для OpenGL ? Ну вот я делаю фон, например, или же движок и буду там использовать изображения. Какой формат как можно лучше подойдет ? Я сторонник PNG, но хочу услышать лучший выбор для таких целей.

Зависит от ваших целей. В принципе, сейчас стандартом де-факто для изображений без потери качества, является `PNG`. Все движки, с которыми я работал последние годы (занимаюсь разработкой игр), используют именно его.

Но тут есть один момент - для повышения производительности (скорости загрузки, например) также используют либо форматы без компрессии (`ARGB8`, `RGB8`, `ARGB4`, `RGB565` и множество других), либо форматы со сжатием, которое поддерживает выбранная платформа/архитектура (`DXT3`, `DXT5`, `PVR`, `ETC`, `ATC` и др).

В случае, когда графики не много, можно обойтись только `PNG`.

> Какие библиотеки самые распространенные в С++ для работы с изображениями ? Конвертация изобр. из одного формата в другой, перевод массива пикселей в изображение и тому подобное.

По поводу библиотек - опять же, полностью зависит от ваших целей. Если вам нужна обработка и операции над изображениями (конвертирование, изменение размеров, эффекты и т.п.) - то, возможно, что наилучшим вариантом будет [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org) (есть в виде отдельной утилиты и в виде DLL).

Если же нет, то тут зависит от используемого окружения. Например, [список форматов](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormatEnum?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryEnum%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryPixels%29), поддерживаемых SDL содержит около 30 определений. При этом, SDL поддерживает загрузку только из `BMP`, но обычно используют также SDL Image, которая поддерживает уже [около двух десятков](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_frame.html) форматов. А, например, [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org) изначально поддерживает `bmp`, `png`, `tga`, `jpg`, `gif`, `psd`, `hdr` и `pic` (с оговоркой, что не каждый из них поддержан на 100%).

> Вопрос из интереса. Как делают в общем компании и опытные программисты, которым нужно работать с изображениями ? Вот они берут готовые библиотеки или пишут свои ? Разработчики тех же движков, допустим.

Когда есть возможность использовать что-то готовое, нужно использовать готовое. Ни к чему просто так "выкидывать" своё время. Многие игровые движки используют сторонние библиотеки - для изображений, для звука, для физики, для работы с файлами и т.п. Вряд ли у вас возникнет желание писать свой Box2d или OpenCV - если только это не является самоцелью - так почему с изображениями должно быть иначе?

Потратить время на создание своего велосипеда всегда можно позже, если появится острая необходимость в этом - например, лицензия не подходит, или нужно отсутствие зависимостей, для работы на неподдерживаемой платформе.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я почему-то не могу найти ссылку на библиотеку для С++..

Comment: Вы про ImageMagick? http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php